# C program crashing because of invalid address

Tags: c, linux, gcc, crash

I am not able to figure out why my program is crashing in the print statements. Pls help.

```
char *
infix_to_postfix(char *string, int str_len, int *new_len) {
*new_len = str_len;
return string;
}
fsm_t *
fsm_nfa_construction(char *string, int str_len) {
    int new_len;
    char *postfix_str = infix_to_postfix(string, str_len, &new_len);
    // return fsm_nfa_construction_internal(postfix_str, new_len);
    printf ("%s\n", postfix_str);
    return NULL;
}
int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char str[32];
    strncpy(str, "ab|*c.\0", strlen("ab|*c.\0"));
    fsm_t *fsm = fsm_nfa_construction(str, strlen(str));
    return 0;
}
(gdb) f 2
#2 0x0000555555556aa8 in fsm_nfa_construction (string=0x7fffffffdc20 "ab|*c.", str_len=6) at fsm.c:715
715 printf ("%s\n", postfix_str);
(gdb) p postfix_str
$3 = 0xffffffffffffdc20 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffdc20>
```

Comment: Your use of `strncpy` is wrong. That's not what `strncpy` is for. Just use `strcpy`

Comment: In other words: `strncpy(str, "ab|*c.\0", strlen("ab|*c.\0"));` --> `strcpy(str, "ab|*c.");

Comment: Or to make it simpler: `char str[32] = "ab|*c.";

Comment: Not that it matter but... `fsm_t` ???

Comment: fsm_t is another data structure, but irrelevant here to know its definition. Also, same crash with strcpy as well.

Comment: probably there are many ways to work-around the problem, but curious to find what is wrong with this simple code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a null terminator issue..

in this line:

```
strncpy(str, "ab|*c.\0", strlen("ab|*c.\0"));
```

due to the length returned by `strlen`, the null terminating character is not being copied into str.  This is because `strlen` detects the length of a string by scanning until it finds a null character, which in this case is embedded in your string literal. To also copy the null terminating character, just add 1 like so:

```
strncpy(str, "ab|*c.\0", strlen("ab|*c.\0")+1);
```

Since str is not initialized, there is no guarantee that the data bytes there are zero's (null terminating characters).  The printf with the %s format specifier works by detecting the null terminating charater too. since there isn't one in your buffer, the print never stops and crashes the program.

This isn't related to your question, but I don't think your support functions here are doing what you expect.  For example, the `infix_to_postfix` function does not do anything useful.  It just copies one integer to another and returns the same pointer passed in.

Comment: still crashes. `strncpy(str, "ab|*c.\0", strlen("ab|*c.\0") + 1);`  added +1. Alsoo, tried memset  0 the str before strncpy. same Crash.

Comment: @AbhishekSagar Can you provide more information on the crash?  'I replicated your program on my system and the +1 fixed the crash for me.  It forces the strncpy to place a null character at the end of the desired string.  So that is definitely a problem, it just might not be your only problem.

Comment: at printf it says the postfix_ptr pointer is invalid.
(gdb) p postfix_str
$1 = 0xffffffffffffdc20 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffdc20>

Comment: I ran with GDB, set a breakpoint at the print statement line (line 12 if my case) and was able to print the string fine.  `(gdb) break test.c:12` 
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400633: file test.c, line 12.
`(gdb) r`
Starting program: /home/snelso/pg/test 

Breakpoint 1, fsm_nfa_construction (string=0x7fffffffde90 "ab|*c.", str_len=6)
    at test.c:12
12     printf ("%s\n", postfix_str);
`(gdb) p postfix_str` 
$1 = 0x7fffffffde90 "ab|*c."